# Parse XML from K2 WCF service and display in Android, and return Html design syntax instead of XML

Tags: android, wcf, xml-parsing, k2

I success to get httpResponse from WCF web service. However, it returns html background design syntax.
Besides, the site is authentication restricted. I am sure I have across the https authentication with specific account.

The site is look like : https://abc/k2services/syncrest.svc/Task/items

**http connection code**

```
public String XMLUrlHttpRequest(String Url, final String userName, final String password) {
```

...

```
try {

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient =GetNewHttpClient();            

        //Http Request
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Host",host);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept","application/xml");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");

        //Http Response
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        System.out.println(httpResponse.toString());
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 404) {

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            xml_string = getASCIIContentFromEntity(httpEntity);
            if(xml_string.isEmpty()){
                Log.w("XML", "isEmpty");
            }else{
                System.out.println(xml_string);
                Log.w("XML", "OK");
                Log.w("XML", xml_string);
            }

        }


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return xml_string;

}
```

**Parse and read XML code**

```
try {

            response = new ParseXML().XMLUrlHttpRequest(Url,userName,password);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.w("Cannot ", "Start");
        }
        String parsedData = "";

        try {

            Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Start");
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

            Datahandler XMLHandler = new Datahandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(XMLHandler);
            InputSource inStream = new InputSource();

            inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));

            xr.parse(inStream);
            Log.w("response ----->",response);
            int i=0;
            ArrayList<Data> DatasList = XMLHandler.getBooksList();
            //for(;i<BooksList.size();i++){
            Data data = DatasList.get(1);
            parsedData = parsedData + "Detail----->\n"; // Can be shown in the application as getting httpResponse
            parsedData = parsedData + "Process Name: " + data.getProcessName() + "\n";    //<---Error points to here, cause no XML content returned. No column sorted
            parsedData = parsedData + "Process FullName: " + data.getProcessFullName() + "\n";


            Log.w("i==",String.valueOf(i));
            Log.w("Data",parsedData);

            Log.w("populating", "Done");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("ParseXML",e );
        }

        return parsedData;

    }
```

**Return httpResponse**

```
<HTML><HEAD><STYLE type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}</STYLE>
<TITLE>Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<DIV id="content">
<P class="heading1">Service</P>
<BR/>
<P class="intro">Method not allowed.</P>
</DIV>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Thanks

Comment: After google searching, 405 error is proof. Assume there is no any error from the web side, we cannot change web.config, only android application can be change. Anyone help please! SOS

Comment: It would be nice to explain HOW you solved your problem :)